# NLog with an Entity Framework connection string?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, connection-string, nlog

I'm trying to use the ['Database' NLog target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target) and would like NLog to read my connection string to avoid having to set it twice in the same config file.  The problem is I have an [Entity Framework-style connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx), so using the `connectionStringName` attribute doesn't work.

In log4net, I can use a [custom AdoNetAppender](http://www.mikebevers.be/blog/2010/09/log4net-custom-adonetappender/) and extract the appropriate pieces of the connection string myself.  Is there any way to customize NLog's Database target so I can pass in an appropriately styled connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog 4.5 added support for parsing connectionstrings from Entity Framework, so they can used directly:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2510

Also NLog DatabaseTarget is no longer sealed, so if needed special handling then one can also do this.

The normal way of doing special parsing-/lookup-logic is to register a custom layoutrenderer and reference that in the ConnectionString-Layout:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer

Answer (score 8):

This problem can be easily solved by configuring logging target in code:

```
    private DatabaseTarget CreateDatabaseTarget()
    {
        var entityFrameworkConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntities"].ConnectionString;
        var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(entityFrameworkConnection);
        var connectionString = builder.ProviderConnectionString;

        var target = new DatabaseTarget()
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionString,
            CommandText = @"insert into Log ([DateTime], [Message]) values (@dateTime, @message);",
            Parameters = {
                new DatabaseParameterInfo("@dateTime", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${date}")), 
                new DatabaseParameterInfo("@message", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${message}")), 
           }
        };
        return target;
    }
```

Then you can register it with your NLog configuration:

```
var target = CreateDatabaseTarget();
LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget("databaseTarget", CreateDatabaseTarget());
LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(new NLog.Config.LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Warn, target));
```

But if you're fine with taking some Nuget dependencies or want a more complete solution, you can take a look at [NLog.Mvc](https://github.com/MikeHanson/NLog.Mvc) and [NLog.EntityFramework](https://github.com/ladenedge/NLog.EntityFramework) repositories who both have nuget packages available...

Comment: It should be noted that the OP is the creator of the NLog.EntityFramework package that you linked to.

Comment: Yep, created as a result of this question having no satisfactory answer at the time.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to customize the built in `DatabaseTarget` because it's `sealed`. 
And there aren't any other extension points because the `DatabaseTarget.InitializeTarget()` will always throw an exception because it cannot create the `DbProviderFactory` form the EF `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`

So with the current NLog version `2.0.0.0` you have to following options:

1. You can duplicate the connection string or you can use the [DatabaseTarget](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target) DB configuration attributes.
2. You can write your own [custom target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-Target) basically from scratch.
3. You can submit a feature request, and wait until it's implemented.

Comment: Dang, I was afraid those were my only options.

Answer (score 1):

A way to get a normal connection string from a DbContext is the following:

```
context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString
```

Assuming you have the connection string in the appropriate format, I think it's easier to configure the target like this:

1) define the target in your config

```
 <target name="database" type="Database" connectionString="${gdc:myConnectionString}">
    <commandText>
      ...
    </commandText>
```

2) set your connection string at run-time

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("myConnectionString", connectionString);
```

This way, you do not hardcode db target behavior.

Comment: This worked for me better than other answers above. In addition, I found this issue on GitHub that explains it well. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2008

Answer (score 1):

Add variable to the NLog.config file

```
<variable name="connectionStringNLog" value="" />
```

and then reference this variable in the target element

```
<target name="my-db"
        xsi:type="Database"
        dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient"        
        connectionString="${var:connectionStringNLog}"
        commandType="StoredProcedure"
        commandText="[dbo].[LogEntryInsert]">
```

and then in your contextfactory c# file add this line to assign the connection string value whether it comes from other config file or a Key Vault:

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["connectionStringNLog"] = conn.ConnectionString;
```